# Jboss Errai and an own Google Guice Module

Tags: gwt, guice, errai

Does anyone know how can I include the Jboss Errai project into a project that already use Google Guice?

The Errai documentation says it uses Guice internally, however I need that my Guice module recognizes the Errai one.

I am getting this error:

```
No implementation for org.jboss.errai.bus.client.framework.RequestDispatcher was bound.
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Errai does support the use of Guice as a way to wire services together on the server. But Errai does *not* use Gin on the client. It uses it's own IOC container: Errai IOC.

Comment: Mike, could you explain how can I do that on the server side? I mean, should I add some Errai module to my guice injector creation?